# Makefile prerequisite variable evaluation

Tags: makefile

I have a large project with multiple Makefiles, and I need to modify the order in which projects are built.  However, I cannot seem to understand when variables that are prerequisites get evaluated.  Everything that I've read seems to indicate that the entire Makefile is parsed before the dependency graph is built, so I don't understand why this sample is not working:

```
OBJECTS=main.o
EXE_NAME=test.exe

$(EXE_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo PREREQUISITES: $^
    @echo OBJECTS: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

#include shape.mk
#----VV---Contents of shape.mk---VV----
OBJECTS+=Shape.o
OBJECTS+=Square.o
Shape.o: Shape.hpp
Square.o: Shape.hpp Square.hpp
#----^^----End of shape.mk-------^^----

main.o: Square.hpp

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    -rm -fr $(OBJECTS) $(EXE_NAME)
```

When I run this Makefile, however, I get:

```
PREREQUISITES: main.o
OBJECTS: main.o Shape.o Square.o
g++  main.o Shape.o Square.o -o test.exe
g++: Shape.o: No such file or directory
g++: Square.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [test.exe] Error 1
```

Why does OBJECT not have the proper value when the dependency graph is built?

Comment: Note that you can also use secondary expansion for that. That way, variables that appear as targets or as prerequisites can be defined _after_ the rules containing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the entire Makefile is parsed before the dependency graph is built, but the the rules and definitions are read in order. You define the `test.exe` rule as

```
test.exe: main.o
  ...
```

You then go on to redefine `OBJECTS`, but you've already committed to that rule, so that's what Make will use to build the graph.

Try this:

```
$(EXE_NAME):  # This will be first, the default target.

include shape.mk                                                               

$(EXE_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue.  So this means that when I write Makefiles, I need to make sure that any variable that is used as a prerequisite is defined before the rule that uses it?  Is the same thing true if I use a variable as a target?